# Json_decode() - возвращает NULL

Tags: json, serialize, redis, php

Создаю **JSON** объект из массива.

При обратной операции `json_decode($param, true);` 
получаю **NULL**.

Данные получаю их хранилища redis, что-то слышал про бинарную форму данных. 
Какие есть решения? Может, в другом формате заносить в Redis?

На выходе от redis:

```
    array(2) { ["{"userslinksTitle":"\u0427\u0430 - YouTube","userslinksDescription":"\u0422\u0430\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0442\u043b\u0438\u0432\u04\u043b\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0439...","userslinksIdUser":"456","userslinksLink":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=PQK85bN-mvY","userslinksPhoto":"","userslinksLinkClear":"www.youtube.com"}"]=> string(10) "1412711193" }
```

**Исходный массив** для `json_encode();`

```
array(7) {
  ["userslinksTitle"]=>
  string(28) "nicolasff/phpredis · GitHub"
  ["userslinksDescription"]=>
  string(36) "phpredis - A PHP extension for Redis"
  ["userslinksIdUser"]=>
  string(3) "457"
  ["userslinksLink"]=>
  string(68) "https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis#zrangebyscore-zrevrangebyscore"
  ["userslinksPhoto"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["userslinksLinkClear"]=>
  string(10) "github.com"
  ["type"]=>
  string(4) "link"
}
```

А это после `Json_encode();`

```
string(300) "{"userslinksTitle":"php - How resolve json null output? - Stack Overflow","userslinksDescription":"","userslinksIdUser":"457","userslinksLink":"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/26254673\/how-resolve-json-null-output","userslinksPhoto":"","userslinksLinkClear":"stackoverflow.com","type":"link"}"
```

Кажется, понял в чем трабл. Redis возвращает данные json в массиве

Comment: А вы не пробовали скинуть в лог то, что сервис получает обратно? Ну, чтобы по гуще не гадать.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: JSON валидный, но располагается почему-то в ключах массива, удостоверьтесь, что вы именно их парсите и что php5-json стоит на машине (из-за лицензионных терок он выделился в отдельный пакет, хотя если б не стоял - скорее всего ругался бы на отсутствующую функцию).

Comment: Не совсем Вас понял, в плане что проверить и в чем удостовериться. С лицензией и установленными модулями все ок.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, в свое время кому-то там в PHP не понравилась строчка из лицензии JSON, кажется, поэтому `json_encode/json_decode` уехали в отдельный пакет php5-json (бесплатный, конечно). Поэтому, *в теории*, `json_decode` на сервере может оказаться любой функцией или ее вообще может не оказаться, поэтому стоит проверить наличие расширения json.

Comment: Теперь ясно - интересный случай. Проверил - стоит такой: `json support enabled
json version 1.2.1`. Я отредактировал вопрос, **добавив** массив, который форматирую в Json.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, еще раз - вывод абсолютно валидный, убедитесь, что вы скармливаете `json_encode()` то, что нужно.